# Is it possible to serve full async vue 3 components from an API?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, async-components

Let's say I want to fetch data from an API, but I also want the shape of this data to be included. Is it possible to fetch a full async vue 3 component from an API ?

How do you proceed from the server and the client point of views ?

Comment: Actually, it's for security purposes. I need a whole page to be accessible only for specific users. And this page is completely different for every users.

Comment: You already can make secure different pages for every user using Nuxt SSR.

Comment: Unless your page layout is top secret. Then I would recommend you different framework.

Comment: Maybe you could explain how to `make secure different pages for every user using Nuxt SSR`?

Comment: There could be many uses to what I'm asking. It's a valid question. For example, [this website](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/distributed-vue-applications-loading-components-via-http/) tried answering the question with vue2.

Comment: Author of this article is saying about different but similar Nuxt.js framework. Nuxt.js already provides "Distributed Vue.js components". When you build your application, the compiler compiles code to different chunks of code and most of them are just components. Your SPA or SSR application just downloading components it needs. If you update some component, just that component will change and other parts of app will be same, user don't need to download whole app again.

Comment: The API in nuxt is meant to be used for example as a gate for external applications to get data from your database, not rendering/serving components.

Comment: You don't want to publish your top secret algorithm for Ziping files because it's 99% more efficient than open source one use API.

Comment: Your question is literally like, "Is it possible to make a spoon using a spoon ?"